# URL Rewrite not working for shared hosting

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a very simple site to test url rewrite on my online host, because my original application worked fine on my local WampServer but didn't work with my online host.

here is my code:

index.php:

```
    <?php

    $p = $_GET['p'];

    $pages = array (

        'home'      => 'home.php',
        'about'     => 'about.php',
        'contact'   => 'contact.php'

    );

    if (isset($pages[$p]))  $page = $pages[$p];

    else                            $page = 'home.php';

    include $page;

?>



<!doctype html>

<html>

    <head></head>

    <body>

        <?php echo $body; ?>

        <br /><br /><br />

        <a href="http://newcryo.com/">HOME</a> - <a href="http://newcryo.com/about/">ABOUT</a> - <a href="http://newcryo.com/contact/">CONTACT</a>

    </body>

</html>
```

home.php:

```
<?php

    $body = '

        <h1>Home</h1>

        This is the home page

    ';

?>
```

about.php:

```
<?php

    $body = '

        <h1>About</h1>

        This is the about page

    ';

?>
```

contact.php:

```
<?php

    $body = '

        <h1>Contact</h1>

        This is the contact page

    ';

?>
```

.htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On



# home
RewriteRule ^$ index.php?p=home [L]

# other pages
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/$ index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

Now when the url is "http://newcryo.com/" it shows the home page content.

But when "http://newcryo.com/about/" or "http://newcryo.com/contact/" it shows nothing and it opens about.php or contact.php directly not within the index.php as for home page

for both it should be translated to "http://newcryo.com/index.php?p=about" but here it renders as "http://newcryo.com/about.php"

My local host is WampServer with PHP 5.4.3 / Apache 2.2.22
My remote host is a OVH perso shared host with PHP 5.4 / Apache 2.2.20

Any suggestion?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MultiViews` can be a problem here.

Change your options to:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
```

Comment: here it works but when I remove the trailing slash it givers a 404 not found

Comment: Your rewrite rule should be like this: `RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ /index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]` Thus making trailing slash optional.